# How to extract specific word from excel cell using awk command?

Tags: awk

I need help on how to extract specific word from csv cell using awk command?

Filename: Auditlog.csv

Column: D

{"CreationTime":"2022-05-24T19:40:38","Id":"034ad6cv-b57c-4d14-8f42-0a312a8c6423","Operation":"UserLoggedIn","OrganizationId":"b54f43fe-5553-34cr-9d67-3ed3b8b1c487","RecordType":15,"ResultStatus":"Success","UserKey":"13f42edc-acc4-2d43-b042-8734d938c23d","UserType":0,"Version":1,"Workload":"AzureActiveDirectory","ClientIP":"192.223.211.111","ObjectId":"00000021-0322-0ff1-ce00-000000000000","UserId":"tturomes@test.com","AzureActiveDirectoryEventType":1,"ExtendedProperties":[{"Name":"ResultStatusDetail","Value":"Success"},{"Name":"UserAgent","Value":"JAS3POPE"},{"Name":"UserAuthenticationMethod","Value":"1"},{"Name":"RequestType","Value":"OAuth2:Token"}],"ModifiedProperties":[],"Actor":[{"ID":"034ad6cv-b57c-4d14-8f42-0a312a8c6423","Type":0},{"ID":"tturomes@test.com","Type":5}],"ActorContextId":"b45f44de-9876-22cf-9d34-3ed3b8b1c987","ActorIpAddress":"192.223.211.111","InterSystemsId":"b10f76da-cbf3-23a7-86d8-98760854baba","IntraSystemId":"022ad6ab-b57c-4d09-8f67-0a983a8c8787","SupportTicketId":"","Target":[{"ID":"00000023-3243-0ff1-ce00-000000009887","Type":0}],"TargetContextId":"b23f34de-9890-23cf-9d34-3ed3b8b1c988","ApplicationId":"00000023-0230-0ff1-ce00-000000000000","DeviceProperties":[{"Name":"BrowserType","Value":"Other"},{"Name":"IsCompliantAndManaged","Value":"False"},{"Name":"SessionId","Value":"b8787err-4afb-9898-bebb-498f8e9898abb"}],"ErrorNumber":"0"}

The word that I want to extract from this single column is ActorIpAddress:192.223.211.111

Can someone help me with extracting using the awk command or any other tools? All of this is in a single column D.

Please Note: All details have been changed to random characters for privacy.

Thanks in advance.
J

Comment: You mention excel a couple of times but your input file is named `Auditlog.csv` so it's probably a CSV file. The fact that you can open a CSV with Excel doesn't make it an Excel file any more than it makes it an awk file since you can open it with awk or a perl file since you can open it with perl. You should get rid of the word `Excel` from your question as it's not relevant and could lead people to thinking your question is about an excel file when it isn't.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and format your sample input, expected output, and attempted code (currently missing) as "Code Blocks" as described there. Your real input file presumably has multiple lines each with multiple columns so don't just post a single column from a single line as your example. Make sure what you post is minimal but adequate to demonstrate your problem, e.g. 3 lines of 3 columns each, where the target column is about 25 characters long of valid JSON should be adequate for yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Audit file is actually a well-formed `json` file, and in this case the much more appropriate and straightforward tool will be `jq`, which you can obtain with your package manager (i.e. `sudo apt install jq`). I am going to give you a brief breakdown of `jq` just in case, but if you just want the value then you can scroll to the bottom for the one liner.

#### 1. How to format the AuditLog.csv `json` file for better readability:

```bash
cat AuditLog.csv | jq
```

The output of the above command ran inside of your terminal should resemble the following (you should get the colors as well, but if you don't, then append the `-C` flag after `jq` in the above command):

```json
{
  "Actor": [
    {
      "ID": "034ad6cv-b57c-4d14-8f42-0a312a8c6423",
      "Type": 0
    },
    {
      "ID": "tturomes@test.com",
      "Type": 5
    }
  ],
  "ActorContextId": "b45f44de-9876-22cf-9d34-3ed3b8b1c987",
  "ActorIpAddress": "192.223.211.111",
  "ApplicationId": "00000023-0230-0ff1-ce00-000000000000",
  "AzureActiveDirectoryEventType": 1,
  "ClientIP": "192.223.211.111",
  "CreationTime": "2022-05-24T19:40:38",
  "DeviceProperties": [
    {
      "Name": "BrowserType",
      "Value": "Other"
    },
    {
      "Name": "IsCompliantAndManaged",
      "Value": "False"
    },
    {
      "Name": "SessionId",
      "Value": "b8787err-4afb-9898-bebb-498f8e9898abb"
    }
  ],
  "ErrorNumber": "0",
  "ExtendedProperties": [
    {
      "Name": "ResultStatusDetail",
      "Value": "Success"
    },
    {
      "Name": "UserAgent",
      "Value": "JAS3POPE"
    },
    {
      "Name": "UserAuthenticationMethod",
      "Value": "1"
    },
    {
      "Name": "RequestType",
      "Value": "OAuth2:Token"
    }
  ],
  "Id": "034ad6cv-b57c-4d14-8f42-0a312a8c6423",
  "InterSystemsId": "b10f76da-cbf3-23a7-86d8-98760854baba",
  "IntraSystemId": "022ad6ab-b57c-4d09-8f67-0a983a8c8787",
  "ModifiedProperties": [],
  "ObjectId": "00000021-0322-0ff1-ce00-000000000000",
  "Operation": "UserLoggedIn",
  "OrganizationId": "b54f43fe-5553-34cr-9d67-3ed3b8b1c487",
  "RecordType": 15,
  "ResultStatus": "Success",
  "SupportTicketId": "",
  "Target": [
    {
      "ID": "00000023-3243-0ff1-ce00-000000009887",
      "Type": 0
    }
  ],
  "TargetContextId": "b23f34de-9890-23cf-9d34-3ed3b8b1c988",
  "UserId": "tturomes@test.com",
  "UserKey": "13f42edc-acc4-2d43-b042-8734d938c23d",
  "UserType": 0,
  "Version": 1,
  "Workload": "AzureActiveDirectory"
}
```

---

#### 2. How to obtain a list of all the top-level keys:

The previous command will provide you with a structured and colorized `json` output, but you still need to parse it as you are looking for one specific value in the log.`jq` can easily get you that and any other value with key=value pairs, i.e. you provide the key and `jq` will give you its value(s). Its syntax has the following format:

` cat [file.json] | jq '.[key].[subkey][.subsubkey]'

- Now, you will typically want to first look through the list of available top-level keys:

```bash
cat AuditLog.csv | jq 'keys'
```

```json
[
  "Actor",
  "ActorContextId",
  "ActorIpAddress",
  "ApplicationId",
  "AzureActiveDirectoryEventType",
  "ClientIP",
  "CreationTime",
  "DeviceProperties",
  "ErrorNumber",
  "ExtendedProperties",
  "Id",
  "InterSystemsId",
  "IntraSystemId",
  "ModifiedProperties",
  "ObjectId",
  "Operation",
  "OrganizationId",
  "RecordType",
  "ResultStatus",
  "SupportTicketId",
  "Target",
  "TargetContextId",
  "UserId",
  "UserKey",
  "UserType",
  "Version",
  "Workload"
]
```

---

#### 3. Final Step - Getting the value corresponding to a given key.

Once you know the name of the key you can then use that to get its stored value(s). In your case, you are specifically looking for the value of `ActorIpAddress` (**Note**:notice the required `.` that is prefixed to the name of the key whenever you are searching for a value):

```json
cat AuditLog.csv | jq '.ActorIpAddress'

"192.223.211.111"
```

---

#### Extra: When you need to get more than one value, or values further down the chain.

Ex.1: getting 'ActorIpAddress, UserId, and UserKey' together.

```json
 cat stack.csv | jq ".ActorIpAddress, .UserId,.UserKey"
"192.223.211.111"
"tturomes@test.com"
"13f42edc-acc4-2d43-b042-8734d938c23d"
```

Ex. 2:  Getting both the value of user agent key "UserAgent" and the key with value of OAuth matching value, and outputting them in a key=value format.

```json
 $cat stack.json | jq -C '.ExtendedProperties[] | select(.Name=="UserAgent" or .Value=="OAuth2:Token") | "\(.Name) = \(.Value)"'
"UserAgent = JAS3POPE"
"RequestType = OAuth2:Token"
```

Comment: The OP titled their input `Column: D` so I expect what they've shown us is just 1 column of their input file, not their whole multi-column input file that they need to isolate column "D" from before parsing it as JSON.